# React Native Dynamic ListView Master Detail

Tags: listview, routes, react-native, components, navigator

Can anyone help me by providing an example of a listview with one row, that on press passes a prop through navigator containing the name of the row to another component? I cannot seem to find any information on this, and the examples and answers I do find have so many different syntaxes that it makes it impossible to know when I am supposed to bind a function verse simple this.state stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You would basically set up your navigate function to accept data as an argument from your ListView `renderRow` method:

```
_navigate(title) {
  this.props.navigator.push({
    name: 'Page2',
    passProps: {
      title
    }
  })
}
```

And then in your renderRow method attach this function like so:

```
renderRow (rowData) {
  return <TouchableOpacity
           style={{height: 60, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
           onPress={() => this._navigate(rowData.title)}>
             <Text>{rowData.title}</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

I set up the working example on RNPlay [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/-tbxbQ).

https://rnplay.org/apps/-tbxbQ

Comment: I still cannot figure out why my navigate is null, Any ideas? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5fa3026514b0930c21633200049f85f6

Comment: Has navigator been passed to the component as a prop?

Comment: I believe so, maybe it is because I am creating my rows on the fly? here is index and detail if you have time to take a look. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5a7ba95d970fb643be37ee637285189e

Comment: Ah, you need `renderScene={ this.renderScene.bind(this) }` vs `renderScene={ this.renderScene }` because you are using class syntax.

Comment: Thanks again mate! literally have spent about 50 hours trying to figure this out. renderscene.bind(this) needed to be changed along with renderrow.bind(this) for anyone reading this in the future.

Comment: Awesome! If you have the ability to accept this as correct, it would be great, if not, glad it worked for you :)